# Cannot update the labels - Reset labels for every time AOS restart

Tags: label, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I imported (from file) the new Labels in to AOT ( I see the new file updated in to  \bin\Application\Appl\Standard folder), but when I restart the AOS I lost my *new* labels and I get the empty/previous file.

I tried to deletethe existing file (move in *temporary* Model and delete it) and import again, but my big trouble happen when I restart the AOS, the Label File (and value too) became empty/previous value.

I use Dynamics AX 2012.

I tried to follow this post: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/199806/label-missing-after-aos-service-restart-in-custom-model-ax-2012-r3/515253 , but unfortunately I continue to have the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you importing the label file? Are you going to the `AOT>Labels`, right click and `Create from File`? Are you verifying you are in the correct `layer` and `model` before doing this? Check the labels in the `AOT` and verify you don't have multiple layers/models of the same label file you're working with.

Comment: Does this happen on an environment that only has one AOS and you are the only user? Have you run the SQL statement from the linked discussion to check if the labels are in the modelstore?

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny. I checked, I don't have multiple model of same labels. I tried to move to model and delete the labels and nothing change. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I deleted from  ModelElementLabel and imported again, but issue stilll exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gathered the info.

To solve the issue I followed these steps.

**I)** Move my Label in _Temporary_Model_ ;

**II)** Stop AOS, delete the _Temporary_Model_, delete all files in folder (*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\\bin\Application\Appl\Standard*) Delete all extensions .ali - .ald - .alc about my Label;

**III)** Delete from SQL `DELETE FROM ModelElementLabel WHERE ModelElementLabel.Module = 'MyLabelPrefix'`;

**IV)** Clean *auc* (*C:\Users\\AppData\Local*) file about my user;

**V)** Start AOS and install my Labels **twice** and check by SQL query 
`SELECT * FROM ModelElementLabel WHERE ModelElementLabel.Module = 'MyLabelPrefix'` if I correctly loaded (if I have the right values in *Text* field)

If I have more than one language, I repeat step *V* , Importand is to obtain in SQL Table *ModelElementLabel* the right values.

In my opinion, I seem to have had corrupt files.

Thanks all for advices.